# Dashboard replacement using ASP.NET

Tags: data-visualization, dashboard, asp.net

Our current set of Dashboards are created in DOMO's Product.  Domo front end talking to SQL Server or Oracle Backend.

We need to move off of the Domo Product and were looking into leveraging some ASP.NET programmers to possibly build this in a non-third party product.

We currently are running Visual Studio 2010 but the latest version is also an option.

Suggestions on how to approach?  Charting controls?  Visualization components?
We would like to keep this pretty "generic"....Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com) provides both development components that will allow for creation of a generic web based dashboard solution using ASP.NET and an end to end Dashboard solution as well.

1. [Essential Studio for ASP.NET](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnet) provides controls for developing your own Dashboard solution.

[Demo samples](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/)

[image: Essential Studio based dashboard]

2. [Syncfusion Dashboard](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) is an end to end Dashboard solution.

The dashboard can be deployed with the dashboard server or embedded in your ASP.NET application.

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

Both products are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and licensing is relatively inexpensive otherwise.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.